# JavaScript: Smart routing in JointJS (performance issue?)

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I have been looking at a JointJS routing demo ( http://www.jointjs.com/demos/routing
), which I managed to apply in my web application. The example only has a single link between 2 elements and only has 3 obstacles, whilst in my application, I have about 50 elements (which can be sources, targets and obstacles at the same time) with over 80 links between them.

I have a list of all the elements on the page: *listOfElements*, and a list of all of the links between them: *listOfLinks*

Following the logic from the JointJS.com link above, I'm doing the following:

```
graph.on('change:position', function(cell) {
    // have any elements been moved? Then reroute all of the links.
    for(var j = 0; j < listOfLinks.length; ++j) {
       if (_.contains(listOfElements, cell)) paper.findViewByModel(listOfLinks).update();
    }
});
```

The above kind of does the trick, but is a huge hit on the performance when I drag the elements around, since every single link is checked whenever I move an element.

1. Is there an efficient way to check for collision of a link and an element in JointJS? I've been digging around, but can't seem to find any information on the matter.
2. Am I really doing something suicidal performance-wise here? Is there a way to speed things up?

I am also open to other suggestions on smart routing besides JointJS. I have also tried jsPlumb, but with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, guys, and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

I have only looked at the example briefly, but it does look strange that you iterate listOfLinks.length times, and send in all the links each of those times.

How about:

```
graph.on('change:position', function(cell) {
    if (_.contains(listOfElements, cell)) {
        for (var i=0; i<listOfLinks.length; i++) {
            paper.findViewByModel(listOfLinks[i]).update();
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to look up how to only update links in the area, unfortunately it only seems to be easy to find overlapping elements. But this is what I came up with:

```
function overlap(rect1, rect2) {
    return !(rect1.right < rect2.left || 
             rect1.left > rect2.right || 
             rect1.bottom < rect2.top || 
             rect1.top > rect2.bottom);
}

graph.on('change:position', function(cell) {
    if (_.contains(listOfElements, cell)) {
        var bbox = paper.findViewByModel(cell);
        _.each(listOfLinks, function(link) {
            var linkView = paper.findViewByModel(link);
            if (overlap(linkView.getBBox(), bbox)) {
                linkView.update();
            }
        });
    }
});
```